# SQL combining fast queries runs forever

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the last payment from a set of payment_ids

The table looks like 
p_id    pay_date    amt

and each p_id may have payments on several days.

So, I am trying to achieve this by first getting a table with the last payment date for each p_id and then try to query for all entries where the payment date is equal to the last payment date.

```
WITH last_date_pay as ( 
SELECT p_id as payment_id, MAX(pay_date) as last_date
FROM payments pmt
GROUP BY p_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM payments pmt
JOIN subacc i USING (p_id)

WHERE a.account in ('ACC')
AND pmt.pay_date = (SELECT last_date FROM last_date_pay WHERE p_id = last_date_pay.payment_id)
```

Each individual query runs almost instantly, whereas the combined query shown above runs seemingly forever. Any hints what I am ding wrong here?

Cheers, C

Comment: What indexes are defined?

Comment: Please post the execution plan and the defined indexes. Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using Oracle. The accepted solution works there. 
I don't understand what indexes you refer to... so can't comment on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the  (SELECT last_date FROM last_date_pay WHERE p_id = last_date_pay.payment_id) into FROM section with JOIN

```
SELECT * 
FROM payments pmt
JOIN subacc i USING (p_id)
JOIN (SELECT last_date,  last_date_pay.payment_id as p_id FROM last_date_pay) sub USING (p_id)
WHERE a.account in ('ACC')
AND pmt.pay_date =sub.last_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a query that visits the table just the once?

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT pmt.*
        ,MAX(pmt.pay_date) OVER (PARTITION BY pmt.p_id) AS last_date
  FROM   payments pmt
) JOIN subacc i USING (p_id)
WHERE i.account in ('ACC') AND pmt.pay_date = pmt.last_date;
```

(I'm assuming `account` is in the `subacc` table)